# How to extract the correlation coefficients of CCA from integrated data in seurat

Tags: r, seurat

I integrated the 2 datasets with canonical correlation analysis. After integration, I need to extract the canonical correlation coefficients from the Seurat integrated dataset. So please let me know how we can get the correlation matrix from the Seurat object.
My integrated dataset is seurat.integrated
`seurat.integrated <- IntegrateData(anchorset = anchors)`

I cannot able to extract the correlation coefficients from the integrated data

Comment: You might get an answer quicker at the Seurat Github site.